# Spring transaction is not rolling back

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public Long credit(int amount, Long accountNumber) throws SQLException {

//Account Information
//Amount would be credit from account and UPDATE in ACCOUNT TABLE       
Account account=accountRepository.findAccountByNumber(accountNumber);       
account.credit(amount);             
accountRepository.update(account);


//SOME RUNTIME EXCEPTION
if(true){
    throw new RuntimeException("Just for testing....");
}



//Transcation Details
//Acount transcation details would be store in TRANSCATION TABLE            
TransactionDetail toTransactionDetail=new TransactionDetail(accountNumber,new Date(),amount,TransactionType.CREDIT);            
Long transactionId=transactionRepository.addTransaction(toTransactionDetail);



return transactionId;

}
```

First amount will be credit then account information will be updated in ACCOUNT table then Transcation information will be insert into TRANSCATION Table, Suppose runtime exception occure between Account Updation and Transcation insertion, Account updation (Account table) did not roll back, What is the problem in roll back ?

Comment: Make sure you have `<tx:annotation-driven />` and that you have a database (and table type) that supports transactions (MySQL with MyISAM tables don't support transactions). Please add some configuration and show us where/how this method is used.

Comment: Can you add spring configuration?